# Sigma algebra of $\mathbb{N}$ and measurable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $S$ the sigma algebra that it is generated from the subsets of $X$:

$\{0,1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5\},\dots$

Describe the measurable functions $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in this sigma algebra.

We see that for every open set $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}$ , $
a<b$, $f^{-1}(a,b)$ must be of the form $\{2m,2m+1\}$,  or $X$, $\emptyset$ or 
 $\{m,m+1\} \cup \{m+1,m+2\}\cup \dots $

Can someone help  me please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Functions measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra are constant on the elements of the said $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: why? this part is that i dont understand

Comment: these functions may be  finite of infinite sequences

Comment: @calculon what? What definition of element are you using? Since $\mathbb{R}$ is an element of the lebesgue sigma algebra and many functions not constant on $\mathbb{R}$ are lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @DRF By element I meant atom. So the sets of the form $\{m,m+1\}$ with $m\geq 0$.

Comment: @Calculon I figured you meant something like that. Makes much more sense but I still don't think it's true. Take the above mentioned $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$ and a trivial $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$). If $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$ (rest constant 1 let's say) you still get every preimages of sets in sigma algebra in sigma algebra since you can't separate $1$ and $2$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @DRF Your example is not a measurable function, if you take equip $\mathbb{N}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra given in the question. The preimage (or inverse image, whatever you want to call it) of $\{1\}$ under $f$ cannot be an element (and here I mean any element) of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Calculon can you explain why? I'm quite certain it's measurable with respect to the sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ I described.

Comment: @Calculon Good explanation (but the atoms are the pairs $\{2m,2m+1\}$, not every $\{m,m+1\}$).

Comment: @Did Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Calculon Why? $\{1\}$ is not in the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ I described. Measurability depends on both $\sigma$-algebras not just the one on the left.

Comment: @DRF I assumed the target $\sigma$-algebra to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, to which all the singletons in $\mathbb{R}$ belong.

Comment: @DRF Implicit in the question is that $\mathbb R$ is endowed with its Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @did Yes to the question it is. Not to the comment though where it's stated without any qualification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculon gave you one of the essential hints for solving the problem. Since you can separate any two real numbers with borel sets (even open sets actually), your functions must be constant on the $\{2m,2m+1\}$ pairs.

The next bit to think about is what sets end up being in your $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$. For this consider that $\mathbb{N}$ is countable and a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable unions.

As the last step take an $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(2m)=f(2m+1)$ for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and consider how a preimage of an arbitrary set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ under this function looks. Notice that for this bit you don't even really need $A$ to be Borel.